# Google App Engine - Role Based Access

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine (GAE).  We will be setting up GADS with our Active Directory.  Are there any methods in the appengine API to determine roles or groups that an authenticated user belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an appengine api, its a google apps api. Look at Admin api, Directory. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/